# Where is the error leading to the infinite loop in this RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is the call in JS:

```
'Москва, Щёлковское шоссе д.3 строение 1 - Торговый Центр Город Хобби - 3 этаж, павильон 310, 105122'.match(/(?:[а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9\-\.\(\)]+\s?)+,?\s?(?:[а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9\-\.\(\)]+\s?)+(?:г|гор|город|п|пос|поселок|д|дер|деревня|ул|улица|пр|просп|пр-т|проспект|п|пл|площадь|ал|аллея|бул|б-р|дор|наб|пер|пр|пр-д|туп|ш|шос|шоссе|к|кор|корп|корпус|стр|строение|зд|зд-е|здание|вор|ворота|д|дом|секция)\.?\s?,?\s?(?:г|гор|город|п|пос|поселок|д|дер|деревня|ул|улица|пр|просп|пр-т|проспект|п|пл|площадь|ал|аллея|бул|б-р|дор|наб|пер|пр|пр-д|туп|ш|шос|шоссе|к|кор|корп|корпус|стр|строение|зд|зд-е|здание|вор|ворота|д|дом|секция)\.?\s?[а-яА-Я0-9ёЁ№\-\/()]+,?\s?(?:г|гор|город|п|пос|поселок|д|дер|деревня|ул|улица|пр|просп|пр-т|проспект|п|пл|площадь|ал|аллея|бул|б-р|дор|наб|пер|пр|пр-д|туп|ш|шос|шоссе|к|кор|корп|корпус|стр|строение|зд|зд-е|здание|вор|ворота|д|дом|секция)\.?\s?[а-яА-Я0-9ёЁ№\-\/()]+/gi)
```

It leads to infinite call, so console will be stuck.
I think here is something wrong, but can't find this error.

Also, I think it's not an error in V8, so guys, look at this pls.
Looks like the bottleneck is the last part `[а-яА-Я0-9ёЁ№\-\/()]+` that leads to searching for the matches in loop.

How can I fix it?

Comment: `(?:[а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9\-\.\(\)]+\s?)+` <- that looks dangerous. That's basically like `(x+)+`, which is exponential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is called [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), resulting from nested quantifiers:

Let's reduce this part

```
(?:[а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9\-\.\(\)]+\s?)+
```

to something more readable:

```
(?:[0-9]+\s?)+
```

Now imagine a number like `12345`. The above regex has several options of matching those:

```
12345
1234, 5
123, 45
123, 4, 5
12, 345
12, 3, 45
12, 34, 5
12, 3, 4, 5
[...]
```

and it must try all of these if the regex fails to match initially - after all, maybe a different combination might work that we haven't tried yet.

So, avoid nested quantifiers, or make sure that they don't allow all those permutations, for example by not making the `\s` optional:

```
(?:[а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9\-\.\(\)]+\s)+
```

or by adding the space to your character class:

```
[а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9\-.()\s]+
```

making the nesting unnecessary.

Comment: Yeap, I found this and now I'm thinking how to avoid these optional spaces, dots, and commas. Thanks, it is the answer.

Comment: You might want to separate them, something like `(?:[а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9]+[-.()\s]+)+[а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9]*`, which would allow both letters and punctuation  to end the string.